# Twitter access permission not been saved in ios 5

Tags: ios, ios5, twitter

My app calls below given function to access Twitter account.

```
[self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountTypeTwitter
                         withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
```

This prompt an alert asking permission to access account. When i say "dont allow" and relaunch (call function again), the alert shows again.

This is happening in `iOS 5`, but not in `iOS 6`. Any clue?